# Can't log in to Kali with a user who is not the root user

Tags: kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux with Virtual Box, after the installation I made another user with `useradd` and `passwd` commands, but I can't Log in... If I put the credentials of this account during the Log in, then the Log in screen is loaded again.

I've tried 2 "solutions" I've found...

1.

During Log in screen Ctrl + Alt + F2 and then:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
reboot
```

2.

In `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` changed the following entry:

```
allowed_users=console
```

to

```
allowed_users=anybody
```

But none worked for me...

The only weird thing I noticed was that at the beginning (I mean, the first time I logged in after the installation) `/etc/apt/sources.list` was empty (it only had 2 commented lines), so I added `deb:http://http/kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free` manually.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't used the right `useradd` combination, have you added your extra user to the respective groups? usually `lp wheel video audio cdrom input usb` and have you created it's `home` directory with `-d`.